# Bitcoin cash testnet core crash

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cash, daemon, raspberry-pi

Everytime when i run bitcoin cash testnet core on raspberry pi 3, it just stops for some reason and debug logs end at loading wallet.

So does the raspberry pi 3 cant handle bitcoin cash testnet wallet?

Here is the log that ends everytime: 
`2018-01-29 00:53:20 init message: Loading wallet...`

Comment: By the way bitcoINd run fine on disablewallet but when wallet enabled, it crash

Comment: It works fine when I deleted the wallet with a lot of transaction in it

Answer (score 1):

Since it works without your wallet file, it is likely that your wallet has some sort of corruption which is causing Bitcoin ABC to error on start. Try starting Bitcoin ABC with `-salvagewallet` and see if it is able to recover the wallet to a working state.

Comment: I don't know why but I run it with empty wallet and it works fine but the wallet that I'm using also used on my laptop will crash the daemon